# Bedeutung von "in zweien"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Aus der [*Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung*](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/wirtschaftspolitik/stromerzeugung-deutschland-braucht-die-kohlekraftwerke-13273398.html):

> Der Blick auf die Landkarte legt politischen Realismus nahe: In den Kohleländern Nordrhein-Westfalen, Brandenburg und Sachsen regiert die SPD mit, **in zweien** stellt sie den Ministerpräsidenten.

Was bedeutet **in zweien** hier? Ich habe im [Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/zwei) geguckt, aber keine Antwort gefunden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Form "*zweien*" statt dem normalen "*zwei*" rührt daher, dass im letzten Teilsatz das Nomen ("*Kohleländer*") aus stilistischen Gründen weggelassen wurde (Ellipse). Stehen die Kardinalzahlen "zwei" oder "drei" [ohne dativisches Nomen, dann werden sie ausnahmsweise flektiert](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Kardinal.html#Anchor-zwei-33869) (normalerweise sind sie unveränderlich). Daher wird aus "*in zwei Kohleländern*" "*in zweien*".

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort *zweien* ist der Dativ von *zwei*.

> viele Grüße von uns zweien

(Der Genitiv lautet übrigens *zweier*.)

> ein Antrag zweier Abgeordneter

Je nach Bedeutung kann die Präposition *in* mit dem Dativ oder mit dem Akkusativ verwendet werden. Laut *Duden* kennzeichnet bei der räumlichen Bedeutung *in* mit Dativ den Ort eines Geschehens, eines Zustands, eines Vorkommens usw. als im Innern, innerhalb von etwas Bestimmtem gelegen.

> der Schlüssel ist in der Tasche
>
> (im übertragenen Sinne) er ist Mitglied in einer Partei

Die Verwendung von *zweien* im in der Frage vorgestellten Satz dient der Einsparung von bereits zuvor genannten Redeteilen.

> In *zwei Kohleländern* stellt *die SPD* den Ministerpräsidenten.
>
> In *zweien* stellt *sie* den Ministerpräsidenten.

Answer (score 1):

In zwei von den erwähnten Bundesländern stellt die SPD den Ministerpräsidenten (laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Ministerpr%C3%A4sidenten_der_deutschen_L%C3%A4nder) nämlich Nordrhein-Westfalen und Brandenburg).

Answer (score 1):

In *zwei von den* (aufgezählten) Bundes-/Kohleländern stellt sie den Ministerpräsidenten.